# How to split screen in 2 in X11?

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, display, x

I'm currently using Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon using 2 monitors. But 1 of my monitors might break down soon. Since both are as old as the other I suspect I will have none a little later.

1 option I want to consider for replacement is 1 big 32:9 monitor. I know it's expensive and it's still a option I want to consider. However, there is 1 big condition.

Is there an option in Linux Mint to split 1 X screen in 2. So I'll basically have 2 16:9 X screens instead of one. And how can I do this?

Comment: Depending on your desktop environment, there may be keyboard shortcuts (either default or not-so-difficult to setup) so that key combinations like "Windows key + left arrow" resizes the current window so that it uses exactly the left half of the screen.

Comment: I'm not talking about snapping my windows to the left of right. But actually splitting my monitor in 2. So linux mint is thinking I'm having 2 monitors instead of 1 big one.

Comment: Your description makes me think of something to do with `xrandr --setmonitor`, so that say the left half of your physical monitor shows the top half of the logical space of the X display, and the physical right shows the logical bottom. I'm not sure how the details would work out, though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can!

To snap the current window to the half the screen, aligned vertically, flush with the left side of the screen, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>LeftCursor</kbd>.  If instead, you want flush right, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>RightCursor</kbd>

Tips courtesy the [DefKey](https://defkey.com/linux-mint-cinnamon-shortcuts) site.